# How does copying object properties in JavaScript actually work?

Tags: javascript, object

Let's take an example of a circle object. When I copy the properties of this object to `RoundButton` with my custom `extend` function, I thought `RoundButton` will get the reference of `area` method from `circle` object.

So if I change the definition of `area` method in `circle` it will also change the `area` property in `RoundButton` but in the console, it remains as it was before. I am really confused if I have not cloned the properties but copied them why it is behaving like that.

```
var circle  = {  
        area: function() {
            return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
        }
    };

function extend(destination, source) {
    for( var k in source ){
        if(source.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            destination[k] = source[k];
        }
    }
    return destination;
}

var RoundButton = function (radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
};

extend(RoundButton.prototype, circle);

console.log(RoundButton.prototype.area);

// ƒ () { return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;}

circle.area = function() {
    return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius * this.radius;
}

console.log(RoundButton.prototype.area);

// ƒ () { return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;}
```

Comment: is `circleFns` defined somewhere else?

Comment: @skyboyer sorry I made a mistake in copy and pasting the code from my local draft, it is `circle` object, just corrected it. thanks

Comment: You copied a function reference. This is nothing special, thats just how js variables work

Comment: You are not cloning, you are creating a reference to the object. Look into deep cloning in javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Advice: I think that you need use method Object.assign() in your function extend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reassign:

```
circle.area = function() {
    return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius * this.radius;
}
```

...the previous `area` function object loses a reference. Any objects that still referenced `circle.area` will keep that same reference, but `circle` itself will now have a different reference, to the new function.

This is what happens with *assignment* and is standard behaviour in JavaScript.

In your example you could get your desired behaviour by not copying `circle`'s properties to the `RoundButton.prototype` object (with `extend`), but to assign `circle` to that `prototype`. That way mutations of the `circle` object will directly affect the `prototype` (since they are the same object reference). So replace:

```
extend(RoundButton.prototype, circle);
```

with:

```
RoundButton.prototype = circle;
```

and it will work like you expected.

Again, with the original version, `RoundButton.prototype` does *not* get a reference to the `circle` object, but to its member values directly (so to the area function). Any mutation of the `circle` object through assignment of values to its own properties, will go unnoticed for that prototype object.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, objects (functions are objects) are assigned to variables through references, unlike the primitive values `string`, `number`, or `boolean`.

Lets say that the function assigned to `circle.area` is referred to by "X".

```
var circle  = {  
    area: function() { // "X"
        return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
    }
};
```

Later on you go and assign this function to a difference variable.

```
var RoundButton = {
    area: circle.area // "X"
};
```

So `RoundButton.area` is also referring to our "X". Now if you do:

```
circle.area = new Function("return 1");
```

You will change the reference of `circle.area`, but `RoundButton.area` still is referring to that "X".